# Based on selection how can I move to another page in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

This is my html code(1st TRY)

```
 <div class="col-md-4" >
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Select  No</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="or" required="">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
    <option v-for="aon in data" v-bind:href="'/recorddetails/'+aon.docId" >{{aon.orno}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So, based on the dropdown, If I select a particular value, I need to move to the recorddetails page with its docId.

When I try this code it is not working.

I also tried the following code(2nd TRY)

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Select No</label>
<select class="form-control" v-model="or" required="" @change="orCost()">
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
<option v-for="aon in data" v-bind:href="'/recorddetails/'+aon.docId" >{{aon.orno}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

My vue js code is

```
methods:{
 orCost: function(e) {
  var vm = this;
  data = {};
  data['or'] = this.or;
  $.ajax({
  url: '/recorddetails/'+this.or,
  data: data,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(e) {
  if (e.status)
  {

  }
  else {

  }
  }
  });
 return false;
 },
},
```

The problem is I am not able to redirect to the recorddetails page. 
Please help me to redirect to the recorddetails page. I am able to get the docId value and all in the orCost(), but they are not redirecting. Please help me to redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying too complicated I guess. Just try this

I have included a form also added a name as no.

```
<form method="post" action="/recorddetails/" name="myform"  class=" form-inline" >
 <div class="col-md-4" >
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Select Or No</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="no" v-model="or" required="" >
 <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
 <option v-for="aon in data" v-bind:value="aon.docId" >{{aon.orno}}</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn search-btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </form>
```